# how can set text viewpageindicator 3

Tags: android, android-viewpager

im using viewpagerindicator jackwharton
how can set text in viewpager ?
i can set text in TestFragmentAdapter but cant scroll down

Comment: Fragments are used as pages for viewPager, now inside fragment layout put scroll_view.

Comment: i am beginer please say more explain

Comment: i try in fragment layout add textview but not work

Comment: use this tutorial of dzone : http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to viewpagerindicator.

**Put the textview inside a ScrollView to make it scrollable.**
Pseudo-Xml:

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<TextView height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**For the coloring of single words** you can use Spannables. See this tutorial: http://androidcocktail.blogspot.de/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

Comment: how can write text in viewpager?

Comment: Please look into this sample app from Google: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Animations.zip They are using Scrollable Text in a ViewPager there.